# How to make my app universal?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make my app universal and for both IOS 8 IOS 7. This macros work perfectly in IOS Simulator but when I try to open it in IOS 7.1 simulator pups up this message in Xcode 6.1 Below is the image.[image]

I have this macros:

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) // iPhone and       iPod touch style UI

#define IS_IPHONE_5_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 568.0f)

#define IS_IPHONE_5_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 736.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) < 568.0f)

#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_5_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_5_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_6 ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_6_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_6_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_6P ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS7 )
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the 7.1 simulator is not installed on your computer (it is not installed by default). Inside Preferences > Downloads see whether it's installed under Components.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is %100 correct! I wish I could give you 1000 upvotes, but I am allowed only one :). I am also marking you answer as answered if anyone will have this problem - here is solution. Thanks again friend! I still need to ad code for IOS 7 version with this macros, simulator is working but crashing, and as somebody say it will be this way until you add some macros and code for it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing as problematic here is not your app's role as a universal app (which means that it is native on iPhone and iPad - that part is working just fine) but as an app that is permitted to run on a system older than its base SDK.

Simply set the deployment target. The easiest way is by editing the project - see the Deployment Target pop-up on the Info tab.

[image]

In that screen shot, the deployment target is 8.1, which means we can't even run on iOS 8, let alone iOS 7! By setting it to, say, 7.0, you would permit use as far back as iOS 7.0.